# PHP: Generate word combination from the word with the same category

Tags: php, mysql

I want to generate two word combination from the word with the same category. Example I have this table:

```
+--------------+----------+
|     Word     | Category |
+--------------+----------+
| human        | social   |
| politic      | social   |
| law          | social   |
| artificial   | science  |
| intelligence | science  |
+--------------+----------+

and I want the output like this:

+-------------------------+----------+
|          Word           | Category |
+-------------------------+----------+
| human-law               | social   |
| human-politic           | social   |
| politic-law             | social   |
| artificial-intelligence | science  |
+-------------------------+----------+
```

But I have no idea how to do that. This is my code, and this code just combine all word without category filter.

Model Class (md_classification):

```
function getWords(){
    $stat = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT(word), category from tb_words group by word, category");
    return $stat->result_array();
}

function getAllCombinations($array){
    $combinations = array();

    foreach ($array as $x)
        foreach ($array as $y) {
            if ($x != $y && !in_array($y . '-' . $x, $combinations))
                array_push($combinations, $x . '-' . $y);
        }
    return $combinations;
}
```

Controller:

```
$getWord = $this->md_classification->getWords();

foreach ($getWord as $row) {
    $word[] = $row['word'];
    $category[] = $row['category'];
}
$result = $this->md_classification->getAllCombinations($word);
```

Comment: Why not 'science-social'? It's equally valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your current getAllCombinations function will give you reverse duplcates since you are iterating on all indexes inside a nested loop.
I think the answer here is using a basic for loop as follows

```
function getAllCombinations($array){
    $combinations = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++)
        for ($j = $i+1; $j < sizeof($array); $j++) 
            if ($array[$i]['category'] == $array[$j]['category'])
                array_push($combinations, $array[$i]['word'] . '-' . $array[$j]['word']);
        
    return $combinations;
}
```

notice that the function should receive the array of results the same way it came from the DB. meaning:

```
$result = $this->md_classification->getAllCombinations($getWord);
```

with this method, you won't get any duplicates since you won't iterate on the same rows twice. hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I can advice the MySQL solution for this problem:

```
select concat(w.Word, ' - ', w1.Word) Words, w.Category
from words w
join words w1 on w.Category = w1.Category
where w.Word < w1.Word
;
```

result:

```
+===========================+==========+
| Words                     | Category |
+===========================+==========+
| human - politic           | social   |
+---------------------------+----------+
| law - politic             | social   |
+---------------------------+----------+
| human - law               | social   |
+---------------------------+----------+
| artificial - intelligence | science  |
+---------------------------+----------+
```

[test SQL code here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=e404868fbc3f6e10c65094b993aa5b60&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)